# Cursor is getting stuck on image in content editable div

Tags: javascript, css, html

Please check below [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7mf1me2u/15/)

```
<div contenteditable="true">
<span class="edit-label">
    Edit me
    <div class="alias-edit-div">
    </div>
</span>
<span>
    Other text1
</span>
<span>
    Other text2
</span>
```

- Mouse over "Edit me" Text and keep your mouse on "edit me" text
- Move cursor from left arrow key you will experience a Jittery effect, cursor is getting stuck when edit icon image is visible on "edit me" text

I want a solution so that user can frequently move cursor using left/right arrow key on the editable div element

Comment: A div inside a span is invalid HTML. Also, `contenteditable` element and its cursor is a native environment-depending feature, you can't fork it. Notice, that the cursor stops at every span when moving forward, it's not just the one with the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can add :

```
[contenteditable="true"]:active .alias-edit-div,
[contenteditable="true"]:focus .alias-edit-div{
  display:none !important;
}
```

to hide de pencil when the user is editing.
So the `.alias-edit-div` will not block the cursor.

Moreover on an UX level it is better to not have the pencil icon displayed when the user is editing the content.

PS : you should consider not using `div` inside `span` because it is not html5 valid.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but when I keep hover on "Edit me" span , display none style as you suggested does not work, and If I make above style as important then edit icon never shows up when cursor is on editable div

Comment: It works on Chrome and FF. I don't know why It does not at your place :(